# Mapper output printed directly to the output file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am new to hadoop and experimenting on few basic map reduce programs . I am running into few peculiar issues . I observed that my mapper output is getting printed directly to output file by bypassing the reducer.

The code is as follows

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;



class WeatherRecord implements Writable {
    public DoubleWritable maxSum; // running sum of TMAX records
    public IntWritable maxCount;  // running count of TMAX records
    public DoubleWritable minSum; // running sum of TMIN records
    public IntWritable minCount; // running count of TMIN records

    // default constructor
    public WeatherRecord(){

        maxSum = new DoubleWritable();
        maxCount= new IntWritable();
        minSum = new DoubleWritable();
        minCount = new IntWritable();
    }

    // custom constructor
    public WeatherRecord(DoubleWritable ms, IntWritable mc, DoubleWritable ms1, IntWritable mc1){
        maxSum = ms;
        maxCount= mc;
        minSum = ms1;
        minCount = mc1;
    }

     /* Getter and setter Methods*/



    //method to get running total of temperature
    public double getMaxSum(){
        return Double.parseDouble(maxSum.toString());
    }

    //method to get running total of temperature
    public double getMinSum(){
        return Double.parseDouble(minSum.toString());
    }

    //method to get Count
    public int getMaxCount(){ return Integer.parseInt(maxCount.toString());}

    //method to get Count
    public int getMinCount(){ return Integer.parseInt(minCount.toString());}

    // method to set count
    public void setMaxCount(int c){
        maxCount = new IntWritable(c);
    }

    // method to set count
    public void setMinCount(int c){
        minCount = new IntWritable(c);
    }

    //method to set reading sum
    public void setMaxSum(double r){
        maxSum = new DoubleWritable(r);
    }

    //method to set reading sum
    public void setMinSum(double r){
        minSum = new DoubleWritable(r);
    }

    // method to serialize object
    public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
        maxSum.write(dataOutput);
        maxCount.write(dataOutput);
        minSum.write(dataOutput);
        minCount.write(dataOutput);
    }

    //method to deserialize object
    public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {
        maxSum.readFields(dataInput);
        maxCount.readFields(dataInput);
        minSum.readFields(dataInput);
        minCount.readFields(dataInput);
    }
}


public class WeatherDriver extends Configured implements Tool{

    public static class WeatherMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text,WeatherRecord > {

      HashMap<String,WeatherRecord> recordMap= new HashMap<String,WeatherRecord>();

        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper.Context context) {
            //the individual records from csv file is split based on ','
            String[] record = value.toString().split(",");

            //station-id is the first field in the file
            String stationId = record[0];

            //record-type(TMAX,TMIN,..) is the third field in the csv file
            String type = record[2];

            //temperature readings are fourth column in the csv file
            double temperature = Double.parseDouble(record[3]);


            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("TMAX") || type.equalsIgnoreCase("TMIN")){

                if(recordMap.containsKey(stationId)){
                    WeatherRecord w = recordMap.get(stationId);
                    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("TMAX")){
                        w.setMaxCount(1 + w.getMaxCount());
                        w.setMaxSum(w.getMaxSum() + temperature);
                    }
                    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("TMIN")){
                        w.setMinCount(1+w.getMinCount());
                        w.setMinSum(w.getMinSum() + temperature);
                    }
                    recordMap.put(stationId,w);
                }
                else{
                    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("TMAX")){
                        recordMap.put(stationId, new WeatherRecord(new DoubleWritable(temperature), new IntWritable(1),
                                new DoubleWritable(0), new IntWritable(0)));
                    }
                    else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("TMIN")){
                        recordMap.put(stationId, new WeatherRecord(new DoubleWritable(0), new IntWritable(0),
                                new DoubleWritable(temperature), new IntWritable(1)));
                    }

                }
            }

        } // end of map method

        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Iterator i =  recordMap.keySet().iterator();
            String stationId="";
            while(i.hasNext()){
                stationId = i.next().toString();

                context.write(new Text(stationId),recordMap.get(stationId));
            }
        } // end of cleanup
    } // end of mapper class


    public static class WeatherReduce extends Reducer<Text, WeatherRecord, Text, Text> {

        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterator<WeatherRecord> values, Reducer<Text, WeatherRecord, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // initializing local variables to compute average
            int maxCount =0;
            int minCount=0;
            double maxSum=0;
            double minSum=0;



            //iterating over list of values to compute average
            while(values.hasNext()){
                WeatherRecord record = values.next();

                maxSum += Double.parseDouble(record.maxSum.toString());
                maxCount += Integer.parseInt(record.maxCount.toString());
                minSum += Double.parseDouble(record.minSum.toString());
                minCount+=Integer.parseInt(record.minCount.toString());

            }

            // logic to handle divide by zero case

            if(minCount==0){
                minCount=1;
            }
            if(maxCount==0){
                maxCount=1;
            }

            System.out.println("Min Sum is" + minSum);

            context.write(new Text(key), new Text(","+(minSum/minCount)+","+(maxSum/maxCount)));


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        String input = args[0];
        String output = args[1];

        Job job = new Job(conf, "weather average");
        job.setJarByClass(WeatherMap.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WeatherMap.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(WeatherRecord.class);

        job.setReducerClass(WeatherReduce.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(input));
        Path outPath = new Path(output);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outPath);
        outPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outPath, true);

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new WeatherDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

The expected output would be 
station_id,average_min_temp,average_max_temp

```
AGE00135039,123.12,11
```

But instead, I am getting this output.By analyzing code, I found out that the context.write from mapper is directly writing to output file

```
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00135039 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00147704 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00147704 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00147704 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00147704 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00147704 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
AGE00147704 WeatherRecord@7df8df85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your job is probably calling the `reduce()` method in the Reducer class because the signature of your `reduce()` method is incorrect. You have:

`protected void reduce(Text key, Iterator<WeatherRecord> values, Context context)`

It should look like:

`protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<WeatherRecord> values, Context context)`

Note the change from `Iterator` to `Iterable`.

One way to try and avoid this is to add the `@Override` annotation to methods you think should be overriding a base implementation, and it will throw a compile time error if you aren't.